# How to select unique?

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I'm working on a live music database and I can't think of how to do a query that gets artists that have events on.

I have two tables: `artist` (containing id, name, description, etc.) and `event_artist` (many to many relationship) having `artist_id` and `event_id` columns.

```
return knex('event_artist')
  .distinct('artist_id')
  .join('artist', 'event_artist.artist_id', 'artist.id')
  .select('*')
  .offset(offset)
  .limit(howMany)
```

This returns duplicate ids, which I don't want. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a query that selects artists rows that have rows in event_artist columns.

In SQL it can be written using [exists](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-subquery.html%20Exists)

```
select
  *
from
  artists as a
where
  exists (
    select
      *
    from
      event_artist as ea
    where
      ea.artist_id = a.id
  )
```

In `knex` it can be written

```
knex('artists as a')
  .whereExists(
    knex
      .select('*')
      .from('event_artists as ea')
      .whereRaw('ea.artist_id = a.id')
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

this should be left join not just Join-

```
return knex('event_artist')
  .leftJoin('artist', 'event_artist.artist_id', 'artist.id')
  .offset(offset)
  .limit(howMany)
```